# SELECT UNTIL in SQL with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, t-sql

I would like to select rows until I found a certain Id which is numeric. If my data is ordered by Id the problem can be solved quite easy.

```
Id    Name
-----------
1     Bob
2     Eve
3     Alice
4     Michael
5     Anne
6     Mike
```

To get all items until Id 4 is found the following SQL statement is sufficient:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Id <= 4
```

If the data is ordered by Name and I still would like to get the items until Id 4 is found I couldn't come up with a good solution.

```
Id    Name
-----------
3     Alice
5     Anne
1     Bob
2     Eve
4     Michael
6     Mike
```

The output of the statement to be defined should be:

```
Id    Name
-----------
3     Alice
5     Anne
1     Bob
2     Eve
4     Michael
```

EDIT 1:

With the following statement the output is almost what I need but missing the item with Id 4.

```
queryable.OrderBy(o => o.Name).TakeWhile(o => o.Id != 4);

Id    Name
-----------
3     Alice
5     Anne
1     Bob
2     Eve
```

Is it possible to include the item with Id 4 too?

EDIT 2:

For now I'm going with this approach:

```
queryable.OrderBy(o => o.Name).TakeWhile(o => o.Id != 4).Union(queryable.Where(o => o.Id == 4))
```

As the Id is unique there should be no problem with the UNION statement. But I'm not sure if this statement is the most effective one.

Comment: Regardless of ordering the select statement will still return all records with an Id less than or equal to 4.

Comment: I'm aware of that. My question is about finding a statement that takes the ordering into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = Users.TakeWhile((u,i)=> i == 0 || Users.ElementAt(i-1).Id != 4);
```

Another approach:

```
var result = Users.TakeWhile(u=>u.Id!=4)
                  .Union(Users.SkipWhile(u=>u.Id!=4).Take(1));
```

Comment: This statement returns 1 item. I think Take(1) is not necessary. If I remove Take(1) the output is almost what I need but missing the item with Id 4.

Comment: This seems to work but I'm not quite sure why. Can you explain it with a few words? :)

Comment: @Moo the point is the use of `ElementAt` to refer to the previous element in the current iteration, at the element of `6` in your example, the previous element is `4` so it stops there and discard the element `6` and all it returned before are the elements from beginning to `4`.

Comment: Thanks, I like this approach! What do you think about "queryable.OrderBy(o => o.Name).TakeWhile(o => o.Id != 4).Union(queryable.Where(o => o.Id == 4))". Which statement is more effective?

Comment: @Moo I don't think it's better, it uses 2 query indeed, you also may have more ids of `4` and the second `Where` will return a collection of items (not just 1 item), so it's wrong.

Answer (score 5):

```
Context.Table.OrderBy(p => p.Name).TakeWhile(p => p.id != 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var results = from n in names.TakeWhile( n => n.Id != 4)
       .Union(names.Where(n => n.Id == 4)) select n;
```